# solving system of equations $2x^2 - 3y = 23; 3y^2 - 8x = 59$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> I couldn't figure out how to solve this:

$2x^2 - 3y = 23$

$3y^2 - 8x = 59$

Comment: Substitution?  $y = \frac {2x^2 - 23}{3}$  You will get a quartic equation.  If someone was nice, they gave you rational roots.  If not, it might be  a challenge to factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first, $3y = (2x^2-23)$. Substituting in the second, we get
$$(2x^2-23)^2 - 24 x = 177$$
Simplifying,
\begin{align*}
4x^4 - 92 x^2 + 529 - 24x - 177 &= 0\\
x^4 - 23x^2 - 6x + 88 = 0
\end{align*}
It is easy to see that 2 and $-4$ are two of the roots. We can now factorize, find the other two roots and substitute in the other equation to find the corresponding values of $y$.